# How to keep memory settings when I upgrade the APP

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, memory, xamarin.forms

My APP has a remember password function in the login page which use "Plugin.Settings.Abstractions.ISettings" to remember it.

Recently, I'm programming a new function and add some setting constants in "ISettings" too.

I want to test if APP upgrade to the new one, will the old settings still kept in the new APP and working fine(for example: the password I have signed in).

I have encountered a problem is that I compile the old APP onto my phone first, when I run the new APP into the phone, all memory settings are erased.

What compile settings in VS I need to set, to help me keep the remembered settings still keep on APP?

Comment: You can use `Preferences`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android to make a test, and set `android:allowBackup="true" android:fullBackupContent="true" ` in your `application` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Settings should be maintained between app deployments